# Coldfusion ORM: Error with caching configuration

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am getting the following error when I try to set up EHCache as the cache provider for ORM while using Coldfusion 11:

> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:264)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1743)
>       at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateConfiguration.java:618)
>       at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateConfiguration.java:602)
>       at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.InitializeORMForApplication(HibernateProvider.java:190)
>       at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateProvider.onPageRequestStart(HibernateProvider.java:147)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.firePageRequestStart(ApplicationFilter.java:644)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:449)
>       at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
>       at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>       at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142)
>       at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
>       at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>       at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>       at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
>       at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>       at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>       at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
>       at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
>       at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>       at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
>       at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor409.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doNext(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:472)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doHttpServletRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:312)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.doFusionRequest(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:192)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorRequestHandler.handle(FusionReactorRequestHandler.java:507)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filter.FusionReactorCoreFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorCoreFilter.java:36)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor408.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.j2ee.filterchain.WrappedFilterChain.doFilter(WrappedFilterChain.java:79)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor407.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.filter.FusionReactorStaticFilter.doFilter(FusionReactorStaticFilter.java:53)
>       at com.intergral.fusionreactor.agent.pointcuts.NewFilterChainPointCut$1.invoke(NewFilterChainPointCut.java:41)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
>       at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
>   1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
>   2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
>   The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
>       at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.(CacheImpl.java:70)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
>       ... 66 more
>   Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
>   1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
>   2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
>   The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
>       at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:529)
>       at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:374)
>       at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.(CacheManager.java:259)
>       at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory.start(EhCacheRegionFactory.java:94)
>       ... 71 more

This is my ormSettings in Application.cfc:

```
this.ormSettings = {
    datasource = "dummy",
    cfcLocation = ["/models"],
    dbCreate = "none",
    logSql = true,
    eventHandling = true,
    eventHandler = "cborm.models.EventHandler",
    autoRebuild = false,
    useDBForMapping = true,
    flustAtRequestEnd = false,
    autoManageSession = false,
    secondarycacheEnabled = true,
    cacheprovider = "ehcache",
    cacheconfig = "C:/Codebase/test/config/ehcache.xml"
};
```

And this is the content of ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="C:/Codebase/test/tmp/ehcache"/>
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
    />
</ehcache>
```

Comment: Seems similar to this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013288/another-unnamed-cachemanager-already-exists-in-the-same-vm-ehcache-2-5

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to restart ColdFusion. Grrr.....